# multiple ar.drones on tum_simulator

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ardrone, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I've been trying to make the ros-gazebo simulator working with 2 or more drones, with no result. Using rostopic list, the topics appear with the right name (/ardrone/takeoff and /ardrone_2/takeoff etc.) but when I send a command, only one drones is receiving them, often with unexpected outcomes (it flies away =( ))

Here is my launch file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
   
  <!-- Start Gazebo with wg world running in (max) realtime -->
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find cvg_sim_gazebo)/worlds/3boxes_room.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    <!-- start gui -->
  <group if="$(arg gui)">
    <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen" required="true"/>
  </group>
   
  <group ns="ardrone">
  <!-- Spawn simulated quadrotor uav -->
  <include file="$(find cvg_sim_gazebo)/launch/spawn_quadrotor_classic.launch" >
    <arg name="model" value="$(find cvg_sim_gazebo)/urdf/quadrotor_sensors.urdf.xacro"/>
    <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 0 -y 0 -z 0.5"
  </include>
  </group>

  <group ns="ardrone_2">
  <!-- Spawn simulated quadrotor uav -->
  <include file="$(find cvg_sim_gazebo)/launch/spawn_quadrotor_classic.launch" >
    <arg name="model" value="$(find cvg_sim_gazebo)/urdf/quadrotor_sensors.urdf.xacro"/>
    <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 1 -y 0 -z 0.5"
  </include>
  </group>
   
</launch>
```

while the spawn_quadrotor_classic launch file is,

```
 <launch>
   <arg name="model" default="$(find cvg_sim_gazebo)/urdf/quadrotor.urdf.xacro"/>
   <arg name="init_pose" />
   <!-- send the robot XML to param server -->
   <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(arg model)'" />
   
   <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
   <node name="spawn_robot" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
   args="-param robot_description
   -urdf
   $(arg init_pose)
   -model quadrotor"
     respawn="false" output="screen"/>
     
   <!-- start robot state publisher -->
   <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen" >
     <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
     <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="" />
   </node>

   <node name="ground_truth_to_tf" pkg="message_to_tf" type="message_to_tf" output="screen">
     <param name="odometry_topic" value="ground_truth/state" />
     <param name="frame_id" value="nav" />
   </node>
   <!-- node name="hector_pose_estimation" pkg="hector_pose_estimation" type="hector_pose_estimation_node" output="screen"/-->

 </launch>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62981/multiple-ar.drones-on-tum_simulator/) by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-05-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aukejw](https://answers.ros.org/users/5025/aukejw/) on 2013-05-31**:
Related question (and answer): http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/896/name-dependent-plugin-topics/

**Comment by [aukejw](https://answers.ros.org/users/5025/aukejw/) on 2013-05-31**:
I can recreate your error, but have not yet found a solution. Controlling two drones from one PC works irl, rostopics are correct.. it seems as if one simulated drone receives all commands based on the ground truth of the other drone (i.e. altd == 0, so go up).

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-05-07**:
Any news regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had multiple (4) quadrotors flying using [hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) (which [tum_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator) is based off) in ROS fuerte and groovy. I think that setup was using tf_prefix, which is not supported anymore with hydro, though. In principle it´s possible to get multiple UAVs working in Gazebo simulation, but making it work will probably require some effort.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yonggun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/18859/yonggun-lee/) on 2014-06-12**:
can you send me how you did more detail to my email please? yongari1290@gmail.com
I also wonder if it also can work with tum_simulator in ROS fuerte

**Comment by [Humberto Beltrao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20626/humberto-beltrao/) on 2014-10-29**:
Could you also send me how this ros-multiple-uav-control is made? I'm using hector_quadrtor and facing the same issue.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
Please try to keep the discussion on the answers.ros.org site, where it can benefit the entire community.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-03**:
Hi, anyone found the solution to this ??

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something new?? I have the same problem...

---

Originally posted by [David Saldana](https://answers.ros.org/users/5274/david-saldana/) with karma: 3 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I contacted the developer some time ago. He said that the simulator is structured in such a way that allows the spawning of only a single robot at each time.

---

Originally posted by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) with karma: 101 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1